# Reload flash plugin in Chrome from Javascript

Tags: javascript, plugins

Are plugins totally exterior from DOM or it is possible to reload a plugin programmatically from Javascript?

Example: Flash often crashes in Chrome due to disparity between Chrome's version and Windows' version of Flash. Would it be feasible to reload it?

Comment: Can't you just reload the flash player on the page? If the whole browser had to be restarted I suppose you could just crash the whole deal. Perhaps `var obj = {};
obj.bye = function(){ return obj.bye() };
obj.bye();`

Comment: I should give it a try, but considering Shockwave crashes at the same time on all opened pages in the browser (Chrome), I have some doubts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well a simple answer should work.

**Nope**

You cannot modify a browser we'll say "underlying plugin structure" using javascript. Meaning no restarting :)

Comment: Ok. I wanted to be sure I didn't miss a cool 'jquery-plugin-restarter-script' somewhere. So, the workaround will remain a page refresh.